# How can I run HC-05 on 8MHz Pro Mini?

Tags: bluetooth, softwareserial, arduino-pro-mini, hc-05

I run an Arduino Pro Mini on ATMega328 3.3V 8MHz, and I am unable to send data over HC-05 breakout board on this frequency, and on 5V 16Mhz, it has no issues.

The Arduino code is down below:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Wire.h>
SoftwareSerial BT(10, 11);
byte value;
unsigned long pmillis_bt = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(19200);
  BT.begin(9600);
}
///////////////////main///////////////////

void loop () {
  if (millis() - pmillis_bt >= 100) {
    byte Data[3];
    byte cmmd[20];
    int insize;
    char str[256];
    int i = analogRead(A0);
    value = BT.read();
    Data[0] = 'a';
    Data[1] = i / 256;
    Data[2] = i % 256;
    sprintf(str, "%d", i, Data[0], Data[1], Data[2]);
    Serial.println(str);
    if (value == 49) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        BT.write(Data[j]);
      value = 0;
    }
    pmillis_bt = millis();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically Arduino Uno Is working On 5v Voltage Level so you can Directly connect the HC-05 Bluetooth module to it using it 4 lines VCC,TX,RX,GND.

But in Pro mini 3.3 V level due to you need to [Generic 3.3V To 5V 2 Channel Logic Level Converter Bi-Directional Module](http://www.amazon.in/Generic-Channel-Converter-Bi-Directional-Module/dp/B011ECG2MM?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=452c9032-ae7a-4c0b-bf42-18085457ab13)

using this you can easily convert the vlotage level.

if you have to make using simple component also using

[SparkFun Logic Level Converter - Bi-Directional](http://file:///C:/Users/Kalarav/Downloads/Logic_Level_Bidirectional.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the HC-05 Module with a power regulator and levelshifter designed for use with Arduinos that typically run with 5V. What you need is the plain HC-05 as can be found on [AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1pcs-hc-05-HC05-RF-Wireless-Bluetooth-Transceiver-Module-RS232-TTL-to-UART-converter-and-adapter/32736755254.html). Those run with 3.3V but it can be tricky to use them in prototypes.

Comment: I do use the breakout board though, not the ones with the pins.